# How Can I Show My Doubly LinkedList Data in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, linked-list, jtable

I've been searching for many hours on how to add linked list data to a Jtable but none of the results I found were satisfying. I'm trying to teach myself java so it's a bit difficult for me. Anyways, here is my code. I know it's probably really bad so please be patient with me and help me in making it better.

```
public class node {

    public node next,pre;
    public String name;
    public double price;

    public node (String n,double p){            
        this (n,p,null,null);
    }

    public node (String n,double p, node ne,node pr){           
        name = n;
        price = p;
        next = ne;
        pre = pr;
    }       
}
```

---

```
public class list {

    public node head, tail;

    public list (){         
        head = tail = null;
    }

    public void addHead (String n,double p){            
        if (head != null){              
            head = new node (n,p,head, null);
            head.next.pre = head;
        }           
        else
            head = tail = new node (n,p);
    }

    public int  size (){            
        int size = 0;
        for(node n = head; n.next != null; n = n.next)
          size++;     
          return size;
    }       
    public String print (){
        String s = "";
        if (head !=null){               
            for (node p = head; p !=null; p = p.next)
                return p.name +"\t"+ p.price;                   
        }           
        return s;           
    }
}
```

---

I don't know what to write in the getValueAt method

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
class gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    list li = new list ();
    JButton ad;
    JTextField t,t1;
    JTextField t2;
    JTable table  = new JTable (new table_model());

    public gui (){          
        setSize(500,500);
        setTitle("DEMO");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        t = new JTextField ("");
        add(t);
        t1 = new JTextField ("");
        add(t1);
        ad = new JButton ("add");
        ad.addActionListener(this);
        add(ad);
        add(table);
    }

    public class table_model extends AbstractTableModel {
        public list data;
        String [] columns = {"Name","Price",
        };          
        public void addList (list data){                
            this.data = data;
        }
        public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns.length;
        }
        public int getRowCount() {
         return data.size();
        }
           public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columns[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
        {            

        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getSource() == ad && !t.equals("")){              
            li.addHead(t.getText(),Integer.parseInt(t1.getText()));         
        }
    }
}

class test{

    public static void main (String [] aed){            
        gui g = new gui();
        g.setVisible (true);            
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use linked list in a table. Table needs an indexed acces to the data structure. Use ArrayList instead. So you can access the element of the row directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely recommend that you use the [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) class from the `java.util` package instead of implementing your own. If you use Java's LinkedList, then it will have the method `T get(int index)` which will return the element at the specified index. Then all you have to do is map your objects properties to the correct column.

```
class MyObj {
    public String name;
    public double price;
}

class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<MyObj> contents;

    public MyTableModel(List<MyObj> contents){
        this.contents = contents;
    } 

    @Override
    public int getRowCount(){
        return this.contents.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount(){
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column){
        MyObj myObj = contents.get(row);

        //map column index to property
        return (column == 0)? myObj.name : myObj.price;
    }
}
```

This does not require a LinkedList specifically. All of the required methods are defined in the [List Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), which the `LinkedList` class of course implements. If you must use your own LinkedList implementation, then you should also implement the List interface. This will allow your implementation to be used wherever a List is required. Then you will be [programming to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface), not an implementation.

Comment: All I have to do is make an object for the LinkedList class inside the gui class and I can store the data to the list right away, correct? Sorry if I sound dumb and thank you very much for the reply

Comment: That would work, however the contents of the table should ideally be a member of the table's Model, not the GUI component. Also, the comments/answers that talk about using an ArrayList instead of a LinkedList are correct. Index lookups on Linked lists are slow, especially for large lists.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing an element *by index* in a linked list requires O(n) operations.

JTable needs this kind of access.

A `getValueAt` for a linked list would look roughly as this: start at the list head, and advance `k-1` times to the next entry, then return the resulting value. Obviously, this isn't fast for large data sets.

In other words: **don't use a linked list model**, but an array-based model, for *tables*.