# How to display data in a jTable using linked lists

Tags: java, sql-server, linked-list

I have a table from my SQL server and I have connected to and and stored all the data in a linked list. I now want to take that data from the linked list created (everything works fine) but when I try to store it in my table named customerTable it doesn't recognize my table. (My GUI is on a different class, so is my linked list and my customer object that I use to initialize get, set methods, so I think it has something to do with that)

Can anybody help me understand how I do this?

I use this code:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) customerTable.getModel();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Show My Doubly LinkedList Data in a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948509/how-can-i-show-my-doubly-linkedlist-data-in-a-jtable)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement interface `TableModel`, to use your existing list as the back of the table model.

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) of the Java Tutorials, on creating table models.

Answer (score 0):

> so is my linked list and my customer object that I use to initialize get, set methods

If you are storing the data in a custom Object, then you need to create a custom `TableModel` for that Object.

Check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step-by-step example on how to create this custom TableModel for your object.